# Issue while installing android sdk

Tags: android

Hi i am installing the android sdk in pc and after installation completed,when i open the eclipse,i am getting the error as follows:

Here is error:

```
This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 or above.
Current version is 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447.
Please update ADT to the latest version.
```

When i click check for Updates,its running and i am getting the window with these options...
Android DDMS,
Android Development Tools,
Android Hierarchy Viewer,
Android Native Development Tools,
Android Traceview,
Tracer for openGL ES.

When i select these and give next,i am getting error as follows and cannot able to proceed further.

Here is the error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1343904087754 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1343904087754)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Tracer for OpenGL ES 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.jar 20.0.2.v201207191942-407447)
Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.jar 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1343904087754 (SharedProfile_SDKProfile 1.0.0.1343904087754)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.jar [20.0.2.v201207191942-407447]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Tracer for OpenGL ES 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685 (com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.group 21.1.0.v201302060044-569685)
To: com.android.ide.eclipse.gldebugger.feature.jar [21.1.0.v201302060044-569685]
```

Please guide me to solve this problem.i am struggling for two days.

Comment: Dont select Tracer for openGL ES. and try again... https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Comment: i have tried but no use.I went to already installed software and i have seen all the 6 items are installed already,how to uninstall this..

Comment: I know its a obvious thing, but still asking that have u restarted eclipse after downloading all the adt updates? also try to download your sdk manager. If nothing works, I would suggest you to delete the whole eclipse and whole padkage folder if at all nothing works. And download it form here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's a Windows PC.

Try uninstalling everything and then re-install in this order

1. Java JDK
2. Android SDK
3. Eclipse SDK
4. ADT Tools Plugin

Make sure you have administrative privileges.

Personally i can recommend a virtual Machine for Java Development only... ;)

Comment: Have you Admin privileges during installing Process on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=339659

You are getting this because there is a conflicting dependency somewhere. For example, if you have plugin A that depends on dependency.X-1.0.0 installed, and try to install plugin B that depends on dependency.X-1.1.0, there is a conflict. When you check for updates, Eclipse will check all plugins and features you have installed in the past. Try to update one thing at a time to identify which update has a conflicting dependency.

Comment: I have tried but no use..I am getting the same problem.When i click the Android SDK Manager,i am getting the error,Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open eclipse ->Goto help->Installation Details->Click on Android Development Tools -> update

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall and install again doing these foloowing steps on a windows pc(if you are using one):

first download the eclipse-SDK-4.2-win32.zip from the eclipse website http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

unzip the files and keep it in any drive
now open the eclipse and open help and click for install new software

if you have downloaded juno use this link  Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
and select the appropriate plugins.